# Regex get name from string c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

hello everybody how i can get `NGG - Acid`

from this string

```
"????log L 06/11/2012 - 06:45:28: \"NGG - Acid<5><STEAM_ID_PENDING><>\" connected, address \"46.49.70.30:27005\"\n\0"
```

I have tried this

```
int start = Data.ToString().IndexOf('"') + 1;
            int end = Data.ToString().IndexOf('<');
            return Data.ToString().Substring(start, end - start);
```

This does not works when  username contains space or symbols

Thank you

`Update` 
this code gets username but is there better solution:

```
if (Data.EndsWith("\"")) Data = Data.Substring(0, Data.Length - 1);
            int start = Data.IndexOf("\"");
            int end = Data.IndexOf("<");
            var val = Data.Substring(start + 1, end - 1 - start);
```

Comment: What part in your string is a user name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match will be in group 1 of

```
\\"(.*?)<
```

If we suppose your desired match is between \" and <

In C# this becomes

```
var c = Regex.Match(@"""????log L 06/11/2012 - 06:45:28: \""NGG - Acid<5><STEAM_ID_PENDING><>\"" connected, address \""46.49.70.30:27005\\""\n\0"""
, @"\\""(.*?)<").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: please see my comment on Khôi`s comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(Data, @"\\""(.+?)<\d+?><ST");

if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but if user name is Acid< it gives only Acid or if name is <Acid result would be empty

Comment: Edited my Regex... but it's always hard to parse logs like this, because there are always cases where it doesn't work properly.